# How to copy data from one table to another in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, relational-database

What I'm trying to do should be really simple. I have two tables with the following columns:

Table 1:
Name, Level

Table 2:
Name, Cost

Name is the primary key.  I want to combine both table's data into one table that has all three columns.  What I've been trying to do is add a Cost column into Table 1 and copy all the Cost values from Table 2 into it.  I've tried numerous suggestions from other threads on this site and I've never had one work for me.  The new Cost column in Table 1 never budged with any new values.  Why?

I am doing this on MySQL Workbench on Ubuntu.

Here's one that I tried using (New cost column already made for Tbl1):

UPDATE Tbl1
SET Cost = (
    SELECT Cost
    FROM Tbl2
    WHERE Name = 'SpecificName')
WHERE Name = 'SpecificName;

This works when I specify individual rows but it doesn't work when I replace Name = 'SpecificName' with something like "Tbl1.Name = Tbl2.Name"

Comment: standard insert-select will do it http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: one option, use INTO ... select name, level, cost INTO NEW_TABLE from tbl...join...tbl... etc

Answer (score 0):

The problem you face is when some names are in one table but not the other.  Here is one method, using a single `create table as`:

```
create table NameLevelCost as 
    select n.name, t1.level, t2.cost
    from (select name from table1
          union
          select name from table2
         ) n left join
         table1 t1
         on t1.name = n.name left join
         table2 t2
         on t2.name = n.name;
```

This assumes that `name` is unique in each of the tables.

Comment: Exact answer didn't work, but it worked when I tweaked the select statement to this: (SELECT T1.name, T1.Level, T2.cost   FROM T1, T2  WHERE T1.name = T2.name)

Answer (score 0):

```
update Tbl1 t1 left join Tbl2 t2 on t2.Name = t1.Name set t1.Cost = t2.Cost;
```